# What is the fastest way to see battery level in Windows 8 Surface tablet via touch?

Tags: windows-8, battery, tablet, microsoft-surface, windows-rt

What is the fastest way to use touch to see battery level on a Windows 8 Surface tablet? Currently it seems that I have to go to the lock screen to see battery level, but that is quite a bit of effort to get to and return from. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swipe in from the right to access the Charms. It will be in the bottom left next to the time.

[image]

Comment: That is fantastic! Quick swipe to see battery, signal strength, and time. Quick swipe again to make it go away.

Comment: Only problem is it doesn't seem to tell you if it's charging and its percentage as a number, even if you try to tap it.